Strange bug where PrimeVue data is not shown if the async call feeding the data returns too quickly
I'm having a very strange hard to debug problem using Vue 3 and the PrimeVue DataTable, where I am feeding data into a PrimeVue DataTable, which requires API calls for the column data and the row data. For some situations, an additional call needs to be made to get default column data, and other times, we use column data from elsewhere, so 1 less API call.
Scenario 1
If we make one Promise based API call for the data and nothing else, the data does not show. In addition, if the table was indeed empty, a "No Results" text in the DataTable would show, but instead thats gone too, so it seems stuck between having data and not? Also the Vue DevTools plugin shows 50 rows of data in the :value prop for the DataTable, so data is available...?
Scenario 2
However, if we make 2 chained promise based API calls (Data and Columns) then the data appears as expected.
Breaking down the issue
I have further narrowed this down to simply wrapping the Scenario 1 call in a dummy Promise with a 100ms setTimeOut delay (To make sure its the timing rather than the extra default data fetched), and then the data shows as expected.
However, given that all the data for the table (column and row data) is reactive, the table should just render when it has it, regardless of race conditions, and just show "No Results" when it does not. The data structure for all resulting API calls is the same, I have compared this already, so its not that the table gets the data in an invalid format.
Unable to share code at this point due to not being able to reproduce it in smaller code sizes, and its too interconnected to other areas. I do understand breaking it down may show the problem, but have tried to break it down with no luck at reproducing.
Any suggestions for where I can look next for debugging / trial and error fault finding?

If I understood this correctly, 2 API calls are made, one to retrieve the columns, and one to retrieve the rows. In that case, could it be that when receiving the column data, the row data are being reset, thus resulting to the "No Results" message?

No, rows are not reset, and the no results message doesnt actually show. its just blank. I'll update and clarify that in the OP. Data is showing in the vue dev tools. which is very strange.

The PrimeVue data table will appear completely empty if it has row data but no column data.  Look to debug the column data for your issue instead.

Interesting, but surely even if the data arrived back first, once the reactive data containing the column data comes back, then the table should render as expected?
Either way, in the end, the PrimeVue datatable gave too many other issues around large datasets that we went with an in-house solution.
